# Google webmaster tools keeps listing errors about urls that don't apear on my site

Tags: google, google-search-console

Google webmaster tools keeps listing errors on my site about urls such as

http://website.com/kulVxMTq1FRqJDMRo 93/f/w8kgNtn9x5EPpXKrKzo=

The problem is that I don't have links with such urls and that GWT doest indicate the where it found the link.

Is there a way to find where those urls come from?

Comment: Is it the same link over and over again, or a randomly changing pattern, have you googled the link?

Comment: website.com in the example is my own site. All urls reported by GWT are different. I have 22K of them reported. Googling the urls didn't help.

Comment: By any chance is this a godaddy registered domain? Does any of this seem familiar http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=0c17fd791ddd3596&hl=en

Comment: Also have you thoroughly checked your site for malware https://www.virustotal.com/

Comment: The site was registered at Gandi.net. I just checked the site, it is clean...

Comment: Hmmm. I'd look at your google cache to make sure you don't have something clever showing you one thing and google another and look yourself up on backlinkwatch.com

Comment: Also check server logs to see where these requests are coming from - is it only googlebot looking for them...

Comment: The site is clean and well ranked by google. I'll give a look at the logs but I strongly suspect that googlebot is the only one requesting those urls. Thanks for your time

Comment: No problem - please post if you figure it out

Answer (score 1):

These may be bots that are searching the web for vulnerabilities or maybe other reasons. You may not be able to stop them from trying, but you can try blacklisting or blocking them if it bothers you enough.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across such pages before. I can't find the link anymore, but what I found then and which sounded plausible, was that some bots and (SEO or performance) checking websites use such URL's to determine if you handle 404's correctly (and not use a soft redirect).

Comment: "I have 22K of them reported" ... 22.000 times? I highly doubt that Google tries to determine correct 404 handling that often ...

Answer (score 0):

There may have been an infected script on there at one point which generated those URLs which is now gone. I would also generate a new sitemap and re-submit it to Google